# How to combine server and client components in Next js 13 while fetching data?

Tags: next.js13, react-server-components

I need to pass token from session (NextAuth) to my api request. But useSession is a hook and I can't use it on server components, but when I add await to a fetching function it becomes a server component.
Here is an example code:

```
"use client";

import axios from "axios";
import { useSession } from "next-auth/react";

const fetchData = (token) => {
  const config = {
    'Authorization': `Token ${token}`
  }
  const response = axios.get('http://myAPI.com/data', config )

  return response.data;
}


export default Home = async () => {
  const {data: session} = useSession();
  const data = await fetchData(session?.token);

  return (
    <main>
    <h1>{data.title}</h1>

    </main>
  )
}
```

So how can I properly solve this problem, if I need hooks while fetching ?

Here is my dependencies:

```
      "dependencies": {
        "@reduxjs/toolkit": "^1.9.5",
        "axios": "^1.4.0",
        "eslint": "8.47.0",
        "eslint-config-next": "13.4.19",
        "formik": "^2.4.3",
        "next": "13.4.19",
        "next-auth": "^4.23.1",
        "react": "18.2.0",
        "react-dom": "18.2.0",
        "react-icons": "^4.10.1",
        "react-redux": "^8.1.2",
        "yup": "^1.2.0"
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to move the `await` inside a `useEffect` hook:

```
export default Home = async () => {
  const {data: session} = useSession();

  const [data, setData] = useState();
  
  useEffect(() => {
    fetchData(session?.token).then(setData);
  }, [])

  return (
    <main>
      <h1>{data?.title}</h1>
    </main>
  )
}
```

The `await` will now not prevent the component from being rendered (that wasn't the case earlier and hence your issue). And once the data is fetched, the component shall be re-rendered with the updated title.